# How to change max_input_vars

Tags: php, xampp

I have a form with over 1000 inputs, it shows warning below:

> Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit 
>   change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

I have changed `max_input_vars` to more than 1500 in `php.ini` file but it does not take effect and shows the same error.

My project details:

- Server: Localhost XAMP
- PHP version: 5.5.15
- System OS: windows 7

How can I clear this warning?

Comment: Check that you are modifying the right `php.ini` file. If you have Apache running, it may use another `php.ini` than the one in your `PHP` repository. Also, do not forget to restart Apache.

Comment: Using CakePHP doesn't affect the answer - it's the same way you'd do so with php.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ASH's suggested

```
ini_set('max_input_vars','2000' );
```

but this never work with ini_set.
You need to set it with **php.ini** or **.htaccess** file only.

Answer (score 4):

Add below code in your .htaccess file

```
php_value max_input_vars 2000
```

you can change value of 2000 to as per your need

Answer (score 2):

For CentOs server - Search for **php.ini** file loaded using below command :

*php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"*

It displays's the loaded configuration file as per below :

*Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini*

Edit the file using vi / vim any command, search for : max_input_vars

Default value shall : 1000, Change it to : 2000 or as per your requirement and Restart the PHP on server.

Works like charm for me always.

Comment: This is the only one that tells you WHERE the php.ini file is and which one is being used.

Answer (score 0):

convert array to string with comma separate from view using java script, then pass value to controller as string & split value to specific character in controller & convert string to array in controller.

```html
in Javascript : array store in list variable

var str = "";
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
 str = str + list[i] + ',';
}
var len = str.length;
return str.substring(0,len-1);


in PHP
explode this string  & convert to array.
$searchValue = explode(",", $searchValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Fedora. You can try finding `php.ini` with

```
php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

After changing `/etc/php.ini` with

```
max_input_vars = 5000
```

error would not go away even after `max_input_vars` changed. Appears it is not enough to restart web server (apache in my case)

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

also needed to

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Answer (score -1):

First  call `phpinfo()` function than you will see:

```
max_input_vars = 1000
```

set `ini_set('max_input_vars','2000' );` in function and restart Apache server.

Comment: [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) will only set the value of `max_input_vars` for the current script execution, so there is no point in restarting Apache. Either use `ini_set` everywhere you need more than `1000` variables, or update `php.ini` and then restard Apache.

Answer (score -2):

Variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0
This Type of error Sloved the first to open php.ini file and after find "max_input_vars" Syntex and After his limit to 1000 to incres and 2000 set.